# Postgres - dblink_connect how to set timeout

Tags: postgresql, settimeout, dblink

I'm using `dblink_connect` inside a postgres function, like this:

```sql
select dblink_connect('gw', 'dbname=databasename port=5432 host=RemoteIP user=username password=pass');
```

When the remote server is down, this `dblink_connect` take a long time to return

> "ERROR:  could not establish connection".

I need to set a timeout to this `dblink_connect` to return error as quick as possible.

I tried something like this:

```sql
begin;
SET session statement_timeout to 5000;
select dblink_connect('gw', 'dbname=databasename port=5432 host=RemoteIP user=username password=pass');
commit;
```

But not worked.

Any idea that I can set timeout ?

Comment: I think the problem is the connection between two databases (maybe they cannot connect to each other). Please check the connection first and make sure the information in dblink_connect is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the connect_timeout, in the connection string:

```
 dblink_connect('gw', 'connect_timeout=2 dbname=databasename port=5432 host=RemoteIP user=username password=pass')
```

While it is blocked waiting for the connection, it is in a state where it can't be interrupted, which is why statement_timeout doesn't work.